# Petaho kettle Java expression to split cell and duplicate value in excel horizontally

Tags: java, excel, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am using Kettle for data migration for moving data, I come across a scenario where i got a excel where the column header is merged, When i read it only the first cell gets the name others are empty, Kettle can only duplicate values vertically, I have a macro which does the exact same thing, But some one has to do it manually, Is there a java code i could run to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide sample header and data for clear understanding purpose.

Comment: [link](http://i68.tinypic.com/34rb02s.png), please find this image in it week is merged when i unmerge week will be in the first column only.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by merged? In the excel file is there one cell with all the values? Is there a separator? If it's not a great deal of columns I'd just manually add them or change them to what I want using a select step. If you'd like to upload files I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think, got the solution. Here Java code is not required. Please follow the step to achieve your result.

**Step1**: Drag and drop **Microsoft Excel Input** to the canvas.And go to **Content** uncheck **Header**.

**Step2**: Go to **!Fields** tab. See the below image and fill up like below image.

[image]

**Step3**:Go to **Additional output fields** tab and then check for **sheet row nr field** and fill up the check box with **row_number**.

**Step4**:Finally, click on preview button. You get the result like below.

[image]

If you see the result. First three rows are unnecessary. You can filter those three rows by using **Filter** step this part I'am not done.

Comment: Sorry,I don't get you, what will you do after adding row number.in step4 second line u have week right and next are null and in col.7 line 2 next week starts, so i need week 1 to be filled from col.2 to col.6 and then week 2 col.7 to col.11.

Comment: Do you want headers also? what do you need headers just filter those rows like row number: 1,2,3. Do you have still doubts ping me on skype, My skype id: panabakavenkatesh